# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'cl' from 'main' (C:\Users\main.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так  и как исправить, чтоб начал работать код, когда запускаешь из файла t.py

main.py:

```py
class Text:
    def __init__(self):
        self.text = set()
    def get_text(self):
        bla-bla-bla...
        return tuple(self.text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cl = Text()
```

t.py:

```py
from main import cl
class NegText:
    def __init__(self):
        self.neg_text = set()

    def analyze(self):
        bla-bla-bla...
        return self.neg_text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text = cl.get_text()
    nt = NegText()
    nt.analyze()
```

Comment: я образно назвала main, это просто собственный модуль, который я могу использовать

Comment: На Python, main условно является точкой входа.

Comment: Убычно в main_module и определяется констукция if __name__ == '__main__'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверка

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

выполняется, только если запущен файл, в котором она находится,
а у вас определение переменной `cl` находится как раз в ней и, следовательно, при импорте переменная не создаётся.

Выход: вынести определение переменной `cl` из блока `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Comment: да действительно, нужно было без if __name__ == '__main__' определить экземпляр класса. спасибо)